# How Can I Add Parentheses to Composable Code Suggestions in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

In Android Studio, when I try to create a composable function using the suggestion tab, the generated function lacks parentheses, and the cursor is directly placed inside the content function.

For instance, when I select the Column component from the suggestions, Android Studio generates the following code:

```
Column {
    [Cursor Here]
}
```

However, I've noticed that some users receive code suggestions with parentheses, and the cursor is placed within these parentheses, like this:

```
Column([Cursor Here]) {
}
```

How can I adjust my settings in Android Studio to achieve this behavior? I've looked through the settings but couldn't find an option related to this.